# require members in bbpress to enter at least one tag

Tags: tags, bbpress

I want to require my forum members to enter **at least one word into the "tags"-line**, when they are creating a new topic.

While exploring the php-files of bbpress, I added the last two lines to the following snippet within **bb_post.php**:

```
    $topic = trim( $_POST['topic'] );
$tags  = trim( $_POST['tags']  );

if ('' == $topic)
    bb_die(__('Please enter a topic title'));

if ('' == $tags)
    bb_die(__('Please enter tags'));
```

In my understanding, that should do the trick - but still it doesn't. Or am I using the wrong file?

My installation uses bbpress within buddypress.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question under Wordpress answers and got an answer that solved the problem. See here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82956/require-tags-for-bbpress-topics/83734#83734